# AttributeError: module 'pydotplus' has no attribute 'graph_from_dot_data'

Tags: python, attributeerror, pydotplus

I'm trying to graph an example decision tree based on the article I found from: [AttributeError: module 'pydotplus' has no attribute 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711604/attributeerror-module-pydotplus-has-no-attribute-node). However, I'm still getting an attribute error:

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation


col_names = ['Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness', 'Insulin', 'BMI', 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction', 'Age', 'Outcome']
# load dataset
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)



#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['Pregnancies', 'Insulin', 'BMI', 'Age','Glucose','BloodPressure','SkinThickness']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima['Outcome']# Target variable


# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test


# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)


from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image
import pydotplus
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

decision_tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3)
decision_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict values for train and test
# train_predictions = decision_tree.predict(X_train)
# test_predictions = decision_tree.predict(X_test)



dot_data = StringIO()

export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file=dot_data,  filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('decision_tree.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

And the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/treePlotter/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
AttributeError: module 'pydotplus' has no attribute 'graph_from_dot_data'
```

Can anyone explain to me whats the problem? Thank you a lot!
Pycharm 3.8

Answer (score 0):

in `pydotplus` the `graph_from_dot_data` is in the `pydotplus.graphviz` package.

use

`pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(...)`